# creating a couple of new tags

Tags: support, tags

I don't have the required rep to create a couple of tags so I thought I'd ask here and perhaps someone else could do it.

If there is another way to propose a tag without having the ability to do it yourself please let me know.

Proposed tags for freelancing.stackexchange: team, ethics

Comment: You should be able to add tags at your reputation level. Have you tried? Where is your question for us to make it at?

Comment: to add tags you need 150.  I have less than that.

Comment: Ah, I was mistaking then

Answer (score 1):

Tags aren't added by some moderator or admin-controlled mechanism (although they are removed that way).

Once you have the rep, just add the tag where you think it's appropriate.

If others use the tag, it'll stick around. If they don't, the tag won't.

Without the rep, you just need to wait until you do have the rep. There's a reason Stack has set specific privileges to specific reputation levels.

I don't think your suggestions are bad by any means, but I don't think they are critical either. "Ethics" is a good one, although I don't know how much use it would get. Perhaps some. "Team", to me, is kind of the opposite of "freelancing". Freelancing most often denotes a sole-proprietor or individual working for themselves. Once you reach the "team" status, that's more of a direct business venture and no longer within the "freelancing" umbrella. But, admittedly, that's *my* interpretation. I'm not stating I'm absolutely correct in that.